# Find Gross from Net and Percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like know if a simple calculation exists that would allow me to determine how much money I need to gross to receive a certain net amount. For example, if my tax rate was 30%, and my goal was to take home 700, I would need to have a Gross salary of $1000.

Comment: Would John Galt actually pay taxes?

Comment: Not in Galt's Gulch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the gross amount needed, and $y$ be the desired net amount, and $r$ be the rate of taxation.

Then,
$$x\times\left(1-\frac{r}{100}\right) = y\\\implies x=\frac{y}{1-\frac{r}{100}} = \frac{100y}{100-r}$$

Comment: the only thing that would change is that 100y would need to change if the value was not between 100 and 1000. For example, if my net goal was 70,000, the calculation would come out to a Million instead of 100k. Changing 100y to just y works in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your tax rate is $r$, written in percent.  If you want your net to be $N$, then we want a gross of:

$$G=\frac{100N}{100-r}$$